# swift: uitableview populated from a local json file stutters heavily while scrolling

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

When the button is tapped to segue to the tableview, it takes about 5 seconds for it to segue. After it finally segues, when the tableview scrolls, it stutters and sometimes crashes. The tableview is populated from a local json file and references local images. The images are optimized to low sizes. What is causing this and how can I optimize/fix my code to stop this from happening?

```
import UIKit

class PDList: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var pdTableView: UITableView!

var pdArt = [Decode]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    json()

    pdTableView.delegate = self
    pdTableView.dataSource = self

}

func json() {

    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "palmdesert", ofType: "json")
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path!)

    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
        self.pdArt = try JSONDecoder().decode([Decode].self, from: data)
    }
    catch {}

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return pdArt.count

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "pdCell")
    let image = UIImage(named: pdArt[indexPath.row].pic)
    cell.textLabel?.text = pdArt[indexPath.row].art
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = pdArt[indexPath.row].artist.capitalized
    cell.imageView?.image = image 

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "pdDetail", sender: self)
    self.pdTableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destination = segue.destination as? PDDetail {
        destination.pdArt = pdArt[(pdTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)!]
    }
}

@IBAction func done(sender: AnyObject) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

}
```

JSON Example:

```
{
  "art": "Agave",
  "desc": "Agave by Michael Watling serves as the City's entry monument and is inspired by the imagery of the agave, a succulent native to the desert.  The stone forms are representative of Palm Desert's many well-managed resources for survival and growth.",
  "artist": "Michael Watling",
  "lat": 33.7215,
  "long": -116.362,
  "pic": "test.png"
  }
```

Time Profile:
[image: Time Profile]
[image: Time Profile2]

Let me know if you need any other information. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why are you creating a new cell each time instead of dequeuing the cells?

Comment: Please fully expand only the main thread (option click) and filter out system calls (with the pop up from the call tree button)

Comment: @WarrenBurton I added the expanded picture to my post above.

Comment: So, what is IndioList and why would it be taking 295ms to allocate a named image? . That will cause a big stutter.

Comment: Also filter down the time selection to just the piece you are interested in.

Comment: @WarrenBurton IndioList is a viewcontroller and I am wondering why it takes so long too.

Comment: @WarrenBurton I updated the second picture in my post to filter down to the time where the lag occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I built a sample `UITableView` project with an asset library of 20 large jpeg images of `4032 × 3024` to feed in via `UIImage(named:)` to my cells.

This was vastly overspec for an image view of `120 x 70` so a max requirement of `360 x 210`.

The time profiler showed this for scrolling in an entirely new batch of 12 cells.

[image]

Roughly 54ms per cell (650/12). However even large JPGs take advantage of hardware decoding so not *too* bad.

A modern iWidget at 60Hz refresh gives you a maximum of 16ms per frame to refresh the cell. So I got stuttering.

Replacing the images with appropriately scaled images (360 x 210 ) gives this.

[image]

Roughly 14ms per cell. The table scrolls mostly smooth.

So the problem here is likely one of these things.

- Your images are too large. Ensure your assets are a pixel size of `3x` the size of the image view.
- Your images are not PNG or JPEG and cannot be handed off to the hardware decoder or treated with `pngcrush`. Make sure your images are PNG or JPEG. e.g GIF would be bad.
- You are using PNG when JPG might be more appropriate. Real world images would be best as JPG. Line art/solid colors would be best as PNG.

Answer (score 0):

Dequeue cells instead of creating new one every time. Change **cellForRow** to the following:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("pdCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
  let image = UIImage(named: pdArt[indexPath.row].pic)
  cell.textLabel?.text = pdArt[indexPath.row].art
  cell.detailTextLabel?.text = pdArt[indexPath.row].artist.capitalized
  cell.imageView?.image = image 

  return cell
}
```

Comment: I replaced my cellForRow with your suggested answer and it continues to stutter while I scroll.

Comment: Did you try commenting out the code that sets the image and see the effect?

Comment: I commented out the image and detail text lines and it still stutters with only the textLabel.

Comment: Use the time profiler instrument to see where the delay is.

Comment: @Paulw11 I added the time profiler picture in my post above.

Comment: You need to drill down into the Time Profile results to see exactly which method is taking a lot of time.  Also, do you get any constraints warning?  Have you set the row height and estimated row height values?

Comment: @Paulw11I'm not too sure how to use the time profiler. I looked into the results and I find threads but I do not know what to do with them. I do not get any constraint warnings. The only thing I set was in the heightForRowAt.

Comment: Go through this tutorial for better understanding of Xcode instruments and how to use them. https://www.raywenderlich.com/166125/instruments-tutorial-swift-getting-started

Comment: I found that after I commented out the line that sets the cell.imageView image that it scrolled perfectly. So the problem is when it is trying to load in the images. How would I better optimize the loading of the images so it does not stutter?

Comment: Is there a link to your project on github? If yes i try to help.

Answer (score 0):

My idea is to make a class or Struct something like this.

```
struct ObjectFromJSON {
    var art = ""
    var desc = ""
    var artist = ""
    var lat = 0.0
    var long = 0.0
    var pic = ""
}
```

where you decode the data create an array:

```
var decodedData = [ObjectFromJSON]()
```

then add all the decoded data to this array. If that will not help then try to add a CocoaPod called SwiftyJSON it makes JSON decoding a breeze and might help.

after decoding just set the info into the ObjectFromJSON object and append it to the decodedData array.

```
let decodedArt = json["art"].stringValue
let decodedDesc = json["desc"].stringValue
let decodedArtist = json["artist"].stringValue
let decodedLat = json["lat"].doubleValue
let decodedLong = json["long"].doubleValue
let decodedPic = json["pic"].stringValue

let newObject = ObjectFromJSON(art: decodedArt, desc: decodedDesc, artist: decodedArtist, lat: decodedLat, long: decodedLong, pic: decodedPic) 

decodedData.append(newObject)
```

this is based on your JSON however if you have more than 1 object in that json than it makes sense to put them into an array and then decoding would look a little different for example if you number the objects than would be something like:

```
let decodedArt = json[0]["art"].stringValue
```

if you have multiple JSON files than the first solution should be fine

Comment: How would I replace the ObjectFromJSON struct values with the values from the Decode struct? I implemented SwiftyJSON and it produce the same results as when I parsed with the method above in my post.

Comment: essentially all you are decoding is a string so when decoding you are creating a new object and filling it's details:

Comment: check my answer edit hope it clarifies a little bit. Also pay attention if you have one JSON file that stores multiple artists then the problem lies in the JSON you have to refactor it to an array of artists. If you have problems with that let me know. However if you have multiple JSON files and the content is what you pasted you should be fine with the code I have added.